# Charts similar to the image

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to ask if someone knows any good gem for creating nice graphs similar to the images bellow. [Forget about before and after. Just the graphs] I think those kind of charts are called **pie-in-pie (donut) chart**

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Google Charts support this kind of chart, try out this gem: https://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts

Comment: I think Google chart does not support pie-in-pie charts.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options.  Rubyvis isn't quite fully developed, to my understanding, but protovis does support donut charts http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/pie.html so you might look at using Rubyvis to do that.

Also, you can accomplish this by using R to graph things.  I know that R lets you do pretty much anything if you are willing to figure out how to do it.  There may be a library that already does what you desire, but I hadn't found it yet.  If nothing else, I'm sure you can use pie charts ( http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/pie.html ) and combinations of pie charts (which can be made into a donut, I'm sure) to get it done.

My favorite way to use R from Ruby is with a slick interface with Rserve, which accomplishes binary level, TCP-IP communication between an instance of R and your ruby script.  Here's a link to the gem. https://rubygems.org/gems/rserve-simpler